# Hibernate one-to-many mapping eager fetch not working

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

There is a one to many relationship between College & student entities.

College

```
@Entity
public class College {

private int collegeId;
private String collegeName;
private List<Student> students;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public int getCollegeId() {
    return collegeId;
}

public void setCollegeId(int collegeId) {
    this.collegeId = collegeId;
}

public String getCollegeName() {
    return collegeName;
}

public void setCollegeName(String collegeName) {
    this.collegeName = collegeName;
}

@OneToMany(targetEntity=Student.class, mappedBy="college", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER ) 
public List<Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
}

public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
    this.students = students;
}

}
```

Student

```
@Entity
public class Student {

private int studentId;
private String studentName;
private College college;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public int getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
}

public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
}

public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
}

public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="college_id")
public College getCollege() {
    return college;
}

public void setCollege(College college) {
    this.college = college;
}

}
```

I am a newbie to hibernate, so based on my understanding if i set the fetchtype as `FetchType.EAGER` then whenever i query for a single college object related student objects are fetched automatically.I have used following query,

```
College college = (College) session.get(College.class, id);
```

`college` object is loaded properly but when i say `college.getStudents()` in return i'll get `null`. Am i missing something or is this the proper way to fetch eagarly.

Comment: I have to ask it: Are you 100% sure that theres data. And please show us your service code.

Comment: That's impossible. Hibernate will never give you a null collection. If it was not eagerly loaded, it would load it lazily, and return a non-null list (empty if the college doesn't have any student). Show us a complete test reproducing the problem, turn SQL logging on, and tell us what *really* happens. The only way for this to happen is if you have just, yourself, in the same session, created the college and left the collection null.

Comment: Please check the configured AccessType. The access attribute lets you control how Hibernate will access the property at runtime. By default, Hibernate will call the property get/set pair. If you specify access="field", Hibernate will bypass the get/set pair and access the field directly, using reflection. You may specify your own strategy for property access by naming a class that implements the interface org.hibernate.property.PropertyAccessor.

Comment: If the collection would contain data and be loaded lazily, then it would throw a `LazyInitializationException` from hibernate (if no session is open). So make sure there is actually data mapped to that field.

Comment: sure your code is fine, please provide your service class code i think you missing the setCollege i.e  student.setCollege(CollegeClassObject);

Comment: mh-dev / JB Nizet / Suken Shah - all you guys are correct i used to fetch records from db before actually committing the persist data.

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks ok, but can you please try below and let us know is it works or not.

*Your line of code in **College.java** :*

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Student.class, mappedBy="college", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER ) 
public List<Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
}
```

*Please try to replace this with :*

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Student.class, mappedBy="college", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER ) 
@JoinColumn(name="college_id") // join column is in table for Student
public List<Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
}
```

Hope this helps you.